# How do I use i18n ? (jhipster)

Tags: java, json, internationalization, jhipster

I want to translate the transaction to the selected language. Languages : Turkish and English .

as the following .json file :

```
{
"navMenu": {
    "hide": "Hide",
    "geoLocate": "Find Your Location",
    "zoomin": "Zoom In",
    "zoomout": "Zoom Out",
    "zoominToSelected": "Zoom In Selected",
    "zoomoutToSelected": "Zoom Out Selected",
}
```

.json file name is navMenu.json. Clicking this button looks other buttons. For example clicking Hide(button name) button  we see other buttons (zoomin,zoomout  etc. button)

now I should write translate tag but how ?

Answer (score 4):

Did you see our documentation at https://jhipster.github.io/development.html ? At the end of the page, there is an explanation on how i18n works with JHipster.

We in fact rely on https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate so this where you should go for more documentation (our policy is not to document third-party tools we are using, but we forward you to their documentation instead)

Comment: I have some concerns because all of them button and  all buttons all connected to a one button. and It made the tooltip feature.Can you give an example in this regard @JulienDubois